# submit null values in Twitter bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datepicker

I am using codeigniter and doctrine.php and I am stuck at this place where when I don't select any value from datepicker it should submit null value in database, but its sending yesterdays date everytime instead.

```
function initDatePicker(datePickerID, dateInput){
    $( "#" + datePickerID )

    // Initializing the datepicker
    .datepicker()

    // Detecting the on change date event
    .on('changeDate', function (data) {
      var date = new Date(data.date);
      var dateString = date.getDate() + '-' + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear();
      $("#" + dateInput).val(dateString);
    });
}
```

Controller

```
 $salesOrder->setDateOfBilling($post_data['date_of_billing']);
  if($date_of_billing)
  {
  $salesOrder->setBillingStatus("Paid");
}
else
{
  $salesOrder->setBillingStatus("Not Paid");
}
  $salesOrder->setDateOfPayment($post_data['date_of_payment']);

  $em->persist($salesOrder);
  $em->flush();
```

Model

```
/**
 * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $date_of_billing;

public function getDateOfBilling()
{
    return $this->date_of_billing;
}

public function setDateOfBilling($date_of_billing)
{
    $this->date_of_billing = new \DateTime($date_of_billing);
}
```

View
This is the form where I use date picker

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Billing</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" name="date_of_billing" id="date_of_billing" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Billing" 

  readonly>
  <div id="billing_date_picker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make it clear what the question is.

Comment: Question is pretty clear to me - if the OP doesn't select a date it selects/posts yesterdays date

Comment: Can we see ajax method of sending values also controller code and model code you are using? Please, update your question. Also check: `var date = new Date(data.date);console.log(date);` what will you get.

Comment: You reminded me `Date.getMonth()` starts from 0. Just... HOW??

Comment: done the changes still same value is getting sent......edited the question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.did changes in the controller and model  for above code and its working...

Controller

```
$billing_date = $post_data['date_of_billing'] === "" ? null : $post_data['date_of_billing'];
  echo $billing_date;
  $salesOrder->setDateOfBilling($post_data['date_of_billing']);

  $salesOrder->setBillingStatus("Paid");
```

Model

```
public function setDateOfBilling($date_of_billing)
{
    if ($date_of_billing == null) {
        $this->date_of_billing = null;
    } else {
        $this->date_of_billing = new \DateTime($date_of_billing);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be problem here " `$( "#" + datePickerID )`"

Try this:

```
var dpid = "#" + datePickerID;
$(dpid).datepicker();
```